# C++ Pointers and Variable Assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, heap-memory

So, I am facing a very very unusual problem with my program. Here is my program

```
    void insertItem (Song *&, Song *&, char ar [], int);
    void printList (Song *);
    void deleteList (Song *&, Song *&);
    void processList (Song *&);

    int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {    
    char * filename = argv[1]; char line [31];


int m, n, a;
------------


    /*
        Head and tail pointer to maintain a list of songs
    */
    Song *head;
    Song *tail;

    if (filename == NULL)
        exit(1);    

    fstream fio;
    fio.open (filename, ios::in);



**fio >> m; fio >> n;**
-----------------------


    // Reading the file
    while (!fio.eof()){


**fio >> a;**
-------------

        fio >> line;


**insertItem (head, tail, line, a);**
-------------------------------------

    }
    fio.close();

    printList (head);



**for (int b = 0; b < n; ++b) processList (head);**
---------------------------------------------------


    cout << "\nDeleting List";
    deleteList (head, tail);
    return 0;
    }
```

I declare 3 static variables (m,n, and a) and I use all three of them. The problem I am facing is that as soon as try to initialize a variable **b** in the for loop, I get a segmentation fault. I debugged it using gdb and the value of the head pointer changes when I try to use the variable **b** in the for loop. On the contrary, if I use a previously used variable like m or a instead of making a new variable for the for loop, it runs absolutely fine. The address of the head pointer doesn't change. Any clue on what might be happening here?

Comment: Try to initialize all your pointers. Using uninitialized pointers leads to _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Also, please show the code for `insertItem`, I guess it modifies `head`?

Comment: Initializing head and tail was the key..! Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two errors in your code: you never initialize `head` and `tail` (so anything you do with them is undefined behavior), and you don't check that your input has succeeded before using it.  (Your first loop should probably be `while ( fio >> line )`.  But you don't want to use `m` or `n` either, unless you've checked that the input succeeded.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So initializing head and tail was the key. For the inputs, I am always sure that the file is populated. Why does pointer un-initialization cause the program to go awry?

Comment: @AmayKataria Because it's undefined behavior.  On most machines, the pointers take on random values, which may or may not point to mapped memory.  (On others, the random value may cause the program to crash if it is simply read.)  As for being sure that the file is populated: you can't ever be sure of anything when reading data from outside your program.